# How profile is managed between the different stackexchange accounts?

Tags: support

I have created my first account on SO, using my google account. Then when I subscribed to other SE site, my differents accounts were always linked and my profile infos are always as I have defined them in SO.

But recently I have notice that in my programmers account age is not displayed. Why?

Other question : if I edit my informations in a SE site does the update will be made in the others?

Comment: @downvoters : Give some reasons please. If I asked this question it's because first I thought it's a bug. But I'm not sure, that's why I ask the reason of this comportement between profiles.

Comment: Don't worry about downvoting--on Meta, all it means is that someone may not necessarily agree with what you're asking, the nature of your question, or something else. It's not always related to the quality of the question on Meta but rather the concept.

Comment: @Purmou Ok, np I don't worry about downvote, I just would like some comments with, in order to improve the quality of my question, it's how I will learn! Downvote alone don't teach so much... So I think a little comment even negative, is always welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are editing your profile, you will notice a pretty large button at the bottom of the page that says "Copy Profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts."

It looks like this:

[image]

If you click this button it will sync all your accounts with the one you are currently editing. So all the information you've entered in the profile you are editing will be copied to the rest of your SE profiles.

(I will say that I'm not sure how it works with empty fields. If a field is empty in the profile you're editing but full in another one and you merge, will the contents of the full one be emptied to exactly match the one you're editing? Suppose that's a question for later.)

As for your first question: unless you copy the data from one profile to another, then each profile will have its own data. As in, each stands for itself. If you have your age set on your StackOverflow profile but not set on your Meta SO profile, then that's how it stays until you copy the data from your SO profile to your Meta SO one.

Comment: Actually I edit once in SO and profile seems to be auto-update when you subscribe in an other SE with the same google account. But in Programmers the update has not been fully successfull. Btw thanks for the tips I will know if I want to edit my profile again.